# Print multiple Pages with wxPython

Tags: python, printing, wxpython

I have a wxPython text editor that I've just added a Printing function to.

I was testing it, and printed a PDF document using MS's Print To PDF.

When I opened the pdf document, Everything looked fine at first, but when i scrolled down to bottom of the page, and there wasn't a second page where there should have been one.

Here is my code:

```
def printwindow(self, event):
    pd = wx.PrintData()
    pd.SetPrinterName("")
    pd.SetOrientation(wx.PORTRAIT)
    pd.SetPaperId(wx.PAPER_A4)
    pd.SetQuality(wx.PRINT_QUALITY_DRAFT)
    pd.SetColour(True)
    pd.SetNoCopies(1)
    pd.SetCollate(True)

    pdd = wx.PrintDialogData()
    pdd.SetPrintData(pd)
    pdd.SetMinPage(1)
    pdd.SetMaxPage(1)
    pdd.SetFromPage(1)
    pdd.SetToPage(1)
    pdd.SetPrintToFile(False)
    pdd.EnablePageNumbers(True)
    pdd.EnableHelp(True)

    dlg = wx.PrintDialog(self, pdd)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        text = self.control.GetText()
        dc = dlg.GetPrintDC()

        dc.StartDoc("MyDoc")
        dc.StartPage()
        dc.SetMapMode(wx.MM_POINTS)

        dc.SetTextForeground("black")
        dc.SetFont(self.font)
        dc.DrawText(text, 50, 100)

        dc.EndPage()
        dc.EndDoc()
        del dc
    else:
        dlg.Destroy()
```

Would anyone know how to print on more than one page? The document is more than one page long.

Comment: `pdd.SetToPage(1)` and `ppd.SetMaxPage(1)` don't look like they are going to help :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the dialog box options but I'll check it out

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Yes, they were GUI config options. The Problem appears to be that `dc.DrawText(text, 50, 100)` only draws as much text as will fit on the specified page size. What I need to do is Start as many pages as is required to fit all the text but no more or less. There is no obvious way to do that listed in the docs.

Comment: Printing is covered in the demonstration examples https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.0.4/ see /samples/printing/printing.py in the `wxPython-demo-4.0.4.tar.gz` tarball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around this:

```py
class Printer(wx.html.HtmlEasyPrinting):

    def __init__(self):
        HtmlEasyPrinting.__init__(self)

    def print(self, text, docname):
        self.SetHeader(docname)
        self.PrintText(text, docname)
```